# Firebase callable functions not making a network call from frontend, promise never returns. Backend function reachable with postman

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a firebase callable function from the frontend, but it is not making a network call and the promise never returns.

I can successfully hit the endpoint with Postman at http://localhost:5001//us-central1/what.

But when I call it from the frontend the promise never returns and apparently no network call is ever made:

[image]

[image]

There are no logs on the backend when the call is made.

I'm quite confused as to why this would be happening and I have been fiddling with it for about 3 hrs now.

So far I have:

- updated my backend firebase-functions from 3.3.0 to 3.24.1
- updated the frontend firebase Javscript SDK from 9.6.9 to 9.23.0
- successfully hit the endpoint with Postman when running it on my local emulator
- deployed the function to see if I get a better outcome when not running the emulator

Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure this out. I can hit other https functions on the backend made with functions.https.onRequest from the frontend.

I'd be quite grateful for any help with this

My code:
FRONTEND
src/config/firebase.js

```
...
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions"

const region = 'us-central1'
const environments = {
  [PRODUCTION]:{...}, 
  [DEVELOPMENT]: {...}
}

export const config = environments[selectedEnvironment]

export let baseUrl 
export let firebaseApp
export let functions

const projectName = "..."
const configureFirebase= () => {
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
  functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp, region)
  baseUrl = `https://${region}-${config.projectId}.cloudfunctions.net/`

  if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost' && useBackendEmulator) {
    /**CONNECT TO EMULATOR **/
    const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
    connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8080);
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
    // const auth = getAuth();
    // connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");

    //connect to the V1 web API in the emulator
    baseUrl = `http://localhost:5001/${projectName}/${region}/`
    /**END CONNECT TO EMULATOR */
  }
  
}
```

src/containers/calltest.js

```
import React from "react"
import {functions} from "../../config/firebase"
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const CallTest = () => {
    const handleClick = async () => {
        try {
            const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp)
            console.log("httpsCallable is ", httpsCallable)
            const callableFunc = httpsCallable(functions, 'what', {timeout: 5000});
            console.log("functions are", functions)
            console.log("callableFunc is ", callableFunc)
            console.log("before callable")
            const response = await callableFunc({name: "boom"})
            console.log("after callable, response is ", response)
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn("errors are ", e)
        }
    }  

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Test the callable func</button>
    )
}

export default CallTest
```

BACKEND

```
require('dotenv').config();
const {functions} = require('./admin')
...
exports.what = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { console.log(" I said what?")})
```

****UPDATE****
I've confirmed that I can hit this endpoint if I just use fetch, so it appears to be something I've done wrong with the Javascript SDK.

```
const CallTest = () => {
    const handleClick = async () => {
        // const callableFunc = httpsCallable(functions, 'what');
        // console.log("callableFunc is ", callableFunc)
        // console.log("before callable")
        // const response = await callableFunc()
        // console.log("after callable, response is ", response)
        const url = `${baseUrl}what`
        
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: {}
            })
        })
        console.log("http response is ", res)
    } 

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Test the callable func</button>
    )
}
```

[image]

***Current frontend logs***
[image]

Comment: In order for the functions emulator to work, you must use connectFunctionsEmulator which I see you have commented out in your code. Also, use the try-catch method in order to see if there are any errors when calling the callable function.

Comment: Thank you Mark, sadly no luck. I've updated the code to reflect this and also specified the region explicitly. But neither has let me hit the backend and the console warn doesn't print anything. Full frontend logs in the update.